# Equal-Weighted RETURNS not EQUALLY-Weighted in R

Tags: r, xts, quantmod

Why is the following portfolio not returning the CORRECT % Return:

```
# Load the packages & download the Stock Symbols
library("xts");library("quantmod");library("PerformanceAnalytics")

e <- new.env()
getSymbols("NPTN;XLRN;PBH;DISCK", from="2014-12-31", env=e)
dataset1 <- CalculateReturns(do.call(merge, eapply(e, Ad)),"discrete")

# Make Equal Weight
EW <- reclass(dataset1 %*% rep(1/ncol(dataset1),ncol(dataset1)), match.to=dataset1)
```

Find the Cumulative Sum of the Portfolio:

```
# I have tried the following both methods:
last(cumsum(na.omit(EW)))

or

Return.cumulative(EW,geometric=FALSE)
```

However the CORRECT Return should be the following:

```
# Assuming I purchased on 01-02-2015 at the close
dataset2 <- do.call(merge, eapply(e, Ad))
RETS <-(coredata(dataset2["2015-06-10",])/coredata((dataset2["2015-01-02",])))-1
# Since this is an equally-weighted portfolio:
sum(RETS)*(1/ncol(RETS))
```

The returns are understated by approximately : 18%

This has also been happening with other equal-weight portfolios but I cannot figure out the reason. Any help is appreciated

Comment: I forgot to include the package: library("PerformanceAnalytics") @Pascal

Comment: `ret1` and `ret2` are the YTD returns with daily rebalancing.  `sum(RETS)/ncol(RETS)` is the return starting with an equally-weighted distribution and doing no rebalancing.

Comment: How would I return the equal weight return with no rebalancing as a cumulative return YTD? Such that the cumulative return = Holding period return using only the returns not the Asset prices? @WaltS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The daily returns for a portfolio formed by  daily rebalancing are given by your `EW`, that is, each day the portfolio begins with the same specified weighting of each asset and then computes the daily return using that weighting.  The cummulative return for the portfolio over a period may be calculated using

```
EW <- EW["2015-01-03/2015-06-10",]
ret1_rebal <- last(cumprod(EW+1)-1)
ret2_rebal <- Return.cumulative(EW,geometric=TRUE)
```

where the code for cummulative returns has been corrected from what was originally posted.

When a portfolio is not rebalanced, the returns for each asset individually acummulate over the period. The value of the portfolio at any time is the sum of these acummulated asset returns weighted by the initial allocation.  This can be computed by

```
dataset1 <- dataset1["2015-01-03/2015-06-10",]
dataset3 <- reclass(cumprod(dataset1+1)-1, match.to=dataset1)
wts <- rep(1,ncol(dataset1))/ncol(dataset1)
EW_no_rebal <- dataset3%*%wts
last(EW_no_rebal)
```

Notice that `last(EW_no_rebal)` is equal to your calculation  `sum(RETS)*(1/ncol(RETS))` of portfolio return computed directly from prices.

```
> last(EW_no_rebal)
[1] 0.4586492
> sum(RETS)*(1/ncol(RETS))
[1] 0.4586492
```